Selenium Identifying Text as Empty Array
I have a python selenium script and I am trying to grab the inventory from Carmax.com as shown in the first screenshot. However, I am getting an empty array [] returned from my print statement.

Here is the html.

Another HTML example:
<div class="number-of-matches">
    <span class="header-value hzn-typography--body-1">45,475</span>
        <span class="header-label"> Matches</span></div>

My code results in just having an empty array [] returned, and not the 44,015  (or 45,475 in second HTML example) I expected.
import socket
import os
import json
import certifi
import ssl
import certifi
import smtplib
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.carmax.com")
time.sleep(8)


try:
    if driver.find_element(By.ID, "header-search-button"):
        driver.find_element(By.ID, "header-search-button").click()
        time.sleep(25)             
        inventory = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'header-value hzn-typography--body-1')
        print(inventory)
            
except:
    time.sleep(3)

Not sure what to do here. It is not like this is hidden text right? Totally visible on the page.

By.CLASS_NAME is going to try to get CSS class by name.  When an element has multiple CSS classes assigned to it they will be separated by spaces.  So it looks like this has class names of "header-value" and "hzn-typography..."... but your locator is looking for "header-value hzn-typography..."  You might instead get by attribute of class.  Something like XPATH of //span[@class="header-value hzn-typography--body-1"]

Sadly, same result of an empty array. I tried two different Xpaths (copied Xpath and full Xpath from my browser. inventory = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="results-header-wrapper"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/span[1]')   also tried  inventory = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '/html/body/main/div[1]/div/section/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/span[1]')

Obviously tried the suggested approach as well, with no avail. Tried this nventory = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, '//span[@class="header-value hzn-typography--body-1]'). and ..... this nventory = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//span[@class="header-value hzn-typography--body-1]')

while testing your locator you might want to check size/count/length of the array.  (or use find_element instead... find_element will throw an exception if not found, while find_elements will return an empty array... catching the exception can sometimes give you further clues...)

you might check for frames/iframes here as that seems to be a common cause of no such element exceptions.  (If the elements you are trying to get are inside the frame, you'd want to switch to it...  use webdriverwait with expected condition of frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt)

Just use XPATH specifying the type of tag and its class, like this:
inventory = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, 
'//span[@class="header-value hzn-typography--body-1"]').text        
print(inventory)

the output
45,223

